# npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v14.6.0

Tags: node.js, npm

so i was taking an online course with codewithmosh.com and he told me to revert to an old version of npm so that his class would make sense. so i reverted to npm v 5.5.1. apparently this was so old of a version that it no longer is usable for npm at all. when i try to install the latest version of npm it tells me this:

npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v14.6.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

my node version is the absoulte latest version of node. but it still tells me that it does not support it. if i try to run npm at all it gives me the same message. i've uninstalled nodejs and deleted all associated packages and files including npm TWICE. and it still reverts back to the same v.5.5.1 and gives me the same message everytime. can anyone help me with this? my hope is i'm just an idiot. but only time will tell. please tell me i'm an idiot and how to fix this!!

Comment: Might be a temporary error when rolling out the latest Node version. You can wait a few days and update NPM, or install a previous version of Node. NVM might make the downgrading process a lot smoother.

Comment: i can't even use npm in order to run an npm install

Comment: also after that warning block the first thing it says is cb.apply is not a function

Comment: NVM is a third-party software (Node Version Manager). It can help you install any Node (and NPM) version

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Rolling back via NVM helped me 

nvm install 13;
nvm use 13;

Answer (score 4):

Cut and paste from another thread:

- delete these two folders from appdata/roaming: "npm" and "npm-cache".

(Type %AppData% into the address bar and hit enter to locate)

- repair Node

Worked for me just now

Comment: To clarify the language here: What is meant here by "repair Node" is to go into Windows Settings -> Apps & Features and used the modify option to run a repair install. At least, that's what I did and it did the trick for me. At first I was thinking there must be `node repair` or similar terminal command; my first though wasn't the graphical Windows tools.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this same problem using NVM, as recommended by Seblor. Install nvm if you don't already have it installed, then use the command:

nvm install node

I was able to continue using npm after that.